# Accessing attribute from python Class to a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, attributes

I have a python Class that contains info of the trading market, but I would like access just one attribute from the entire class. any idea on how to do this? thank you.

I have tried this :

```
class StockDataWebSocket:
    web_socket_symbol_list = []
    web_socket_instance_dict = {}

    def __init__(self, symbol):
         self.price = None
         self.last_price = 0
symbol = 'test'       
instance = StockDataWebSocket(symbol)
StockDataWebSocket.web_socket_symbol_list.append(symbol)
StockDataWebSocket.web_socket_instance_dict[symbol] = instance.last_price

last_price = StockDataWebSocket.web_socket_instance_dict[symbol].last_price
print (last_price)
```

i would like to get the 0, but i am getting:NameError: name 'last_price' is not defined

Comment: You are passing `symbol ` to the `StockDataWebSocket` class and didn't set `symbol` value to any class variables in `__init__` function.

Comment: so, from newlly created class, how can i access the the last price in the web socket instance dict?

Comment: Please fix your indentation. For some reason you edited it in a way that can't possibly be correct. Also when giving an error, attach the full trace please

Comment: @EstebanG.Gutierrez according to your solution, just change this line `last_price = StockDataWebSocket.web_socket_instance_dict[symbol]` before the last print statement.